# Trouble launching active_record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I'm having a hard time launching active_record from my ruby script. I get :

Unable to activate activemodel-3.0.9, because i18n-0.6.0 conflicts with i18n (~> 0.5.0) (Gem::LoadError)

I'm using RVM on ruby-1.9.2-p180

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove all versions of i18n. `gem uninstall i18n`

now write `gem 'rails', '3.0.9'` in your gemfile. 
Delete gemfile.lock

run `bundle install`